# How to write a background service in Android?

Tags: android, linux

The "service" here is different form one of the application components "service" in Android. I mean that people can not see the app icon in launcher, and, the can not see the app in the program manager in Android.
The most important is that I don't want the user notice the existence of the app.
Is that possible? Is it a "service" in Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without ROM modifications, you can't make a linux service. I will tell you what you CAN do.

First, your requirements

1. **Not see the app icon in launcher:** This can be done by simply not having an activity that supports the ACTION.MAIN and CATEGORY.LAUNCHER intents.
2. **Not see the app in program manager:** Unfortunately for you (but fortunately for all users) you can't get around this with a normal application.
3. **Have a service run "all the time":** The best you can do here is start a foreground service upon boot of the device. This will cause a notification to be in the users notification bar, but its really the best you can do on stock phones.

Comment: you misspelled fortunately in the second item.

Comment: Maybe I should have said "Unfortunately for you, but fortunately for all users"

Comment: Can I escape from the notification bar?

Comment: If you make the service a regular service (not a foreground service), it does not require a notification. However, if you do that, the service will be more likely to be killed whenever the phone is running low on memory space. If you use the `onStartCommand` properly for the service, you might be able to have Android try harder to bring your service back to life once it dies. Finally, I HIGHLY suggest that you use the notification so the user knows what work you are doing. Users like to know what is running on their behalf and using up their battery life.